# change entire column and row in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, multiple-columns, onchange

how can I change the positions of entire row and columns in a matrix [nxm]? For example, I want to change my entire 10th row and 10th column into entire 1st column and 1st row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To replace row `10` with row `1`

```
M(10,:) = M(1,:)
```

To swap rows `10` and `1`

```
M([10,1],:) = M([1,10],:)
```

Likewise for columns

Answer (score 2):

A dummy example:

```
A = magic(11)

n = 10;
A(n,:) = A(1,:);
A(:,n) = A(:,1);

A
```